# Oracle Select statement without using listagg

Tags: oracle, join, select, listagg

DB : Oracle 11G

Below is a query subset result in which I want to fetch only ID =1, also i want to display if this value is there in the result
NAME = 'S123', if its there return the output as an indicator in the query result

```
  ID, NAME,....(other columns)
        1, 'I123',...
        3, 'S123',...
        4, 'W123',...
        6, 'C123',...    
        ....,
        ....,

eg., output
ID, NAME , value_present_ind('S123')
1, 'I123', 'Y'
```

without using sub-queries on the select statement
without using listagg

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH demo_data AS ( SELECT 1 AS ID, 'I123' AS NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'S123' AS NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'W123' AS NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 AS ID, 'C123' AS NAME FROM DUAL )
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN id ELSE 0 END) AS id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'I123' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS value_present_ind
  FROM demo_data;
```